# Debugger command syntax explaination

Tags: windows, debugging, notepad

I can view the `LDR_DATA_ENTRY_TABLE` with this line:

```
!list -x "dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY" @@C++(&@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList)
```

What do the various part of this do?

---

What bit is the *pointer at the end*?

Apparently I can see the `KRNL_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` by replacing the pointer at the end with `nt!PsActiveModuleList`.

Comment: This executes a command of the form `!list -x "Commands" StartAddress`, which executes the command(s) specified by `-x` for each element of the linked list that starts at `StartAddress`. To get the start address, it uses the C++ expression `&@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList`, where `@$peb` is a built-in variable that references the Process Environment Block (PEB) of the current process.

Comment: @eryksun Is `peb` the pointer then?

Comment: @eryksun OK, I can evaluate `@@C++(&@$peb->Ldr->InLoadOrderModuleList)` on its own.  That gives me `00007ffd``5a3613b0`.